# Can you define multiple TargetTypes for one XAML style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

In HTML/CSS you can define a style which can be applied to many types of elements, e.g.:

```
.highlight {
    color:red;
}
```

can be applied to both P and DIV, e.g.:

```
<p class="highlight">this will be highlighted</p>
<div class="highlight">this will also be highlighted</div>
```

but in XAML you seem to have to define the TargetType for styles, otherwise you get an error:

```
<Style x:Key="formRowLabel" TargetType="TextBlock">
```

is there a way to allow a XAML style to be applied to multiple elements or even to leave it open as in CSS?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The setters in WPF styles are checked during compile time; CSS styles are applied dynamically.

You have to specify a type so that WPF can resolve the properties in the setters to the dependency properties of that type.

You can set the target type to base classes that contain the properties you want and then apply that style to derived classes. For example, you could create a style for Control objects and then apply it to multiple types of controls (Button, TextBox, CheckBox, etc)

```
<Style x:Key="Highlight" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

...

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Highlight}" Content="Test"/>
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Highlight}" Text="Test"/>
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource Highlight}" Content="Test"/>
```

Comment: Yes but what if you wish to apply it to Buttons and Textboxes but not Checkboxes?

Comment: You can apply it to whatever you wish. This style must be applied to controls. If will only be applied to ALL controls if you remove the 'x:Key="Highlight"'. If you don't want it applied to CheckBoxes, leave off the 'Style=' property.

Comment: Clarification: Remove 'x:Key="Highlight"' from the Style definition to apply the Style to ALL instances of that type. With the key, remove the 'Style="{StaticResource Highlight}"' from the control to remove the Style from that control.

Comment: But if I want to set the FontStyle property of a TextBox and a TextBlock. How can I do because TextBlock doesn't inherit from Control ?

Comment: You can create a separate Style specifically for TextBlock. If you want to share the style across multiple types of elements/controls, you will have to have the style target a parent class, like FrameworkElement or Control (which does not work for TextBlock). Find a common parent. If you want to add details for TextBlocks only (like the FontStyle), you can use the BasedOn attribute on the style to base one style on a previously defined style.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It does not work - styles are not applied to derived types. See the question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026635/setting-a-styles-targettype-property-to-a-base-class

Comment: @Al-Muhandis It does work if you specify the style you want to use, like he is doing here: `Style="{StaticResource Highlight}"`

Comment: this solution does not work when you try to use it on custom items that installed using packages as they are not derived from the Control class....is there another approach?

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException : ''Control' TargetType does not match type of element 'TextBlock'.'

Answer (score 53):

```
<!-- Header text style -->
<Style x:Key="headerTextStyle">
    <Setter Property="Label.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Label.FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Label.FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="#0066cc"></Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Label style -->
<Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5" />
</Style>
```

I think both of these methods of declaring a style might answer your question. 
In the first one, there is no TargetType specified, but the property names are prefixed with 'Label'. In the second one, the style is created for Label objects.

Another method to do it is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="commonStyle" TargetType="Control">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
  </Style>
  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource commonStyle}" TargetType="ListBox"/>
  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource commonStyle}" TargetType="ComboBox"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: headerTextStyle can still only be applied to Label and classes that derive from it, therefore you gain nothing from leaving the TargetType out.

Comment: @Steve: I think this one might answer your doubt.

Comment: for the first example, you can replace `Label` with `UIElement` to make it work generally across multiple types of controls

Comment: The "Another method" section is a great option that lets you avoid cluttering your control markup.  If you do it that way, you don't have to have a style attribute on your controls at all, as long as you have a style for each control type.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to apply a style to a Textblock and a TextBox but the selected answer didn't work for me because Textblock doesn't inherit from Control, in my case I wanted to affect the Visibility property, so I used **FrameworkElement**

```
<Style x:Key="ShowIfRequiredStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowIfRequiredStyle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ShowIfRequiredStyle}"/>
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ShowIfRequiredStyle}"/>
```

This works for the Visibility property because both items inherit from Frameworkelement and the property is defined there. Of course this will not work for properties defined only in Control, you can search the hierarchy tree and try to find a base class, anyway I thought this could help someone since this is a top search result and the selected answer is a little incomplete.

Comment: yes TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" worked for me not the 'control'

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative answer to the question. You CAN leave the TargetType parameter off the style altogether which will allow it to apply to various different controls, but only if you prefix the property name with "Control."

```
<Style x:Key="Highlight">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
</Style>
```

Obviously, this only works for properties of the base control class. If you tried to set ItemsSource say, it would fail because there is no Control.ItemsSource

Comment: By doing this you are implicitly indicating a TargetType; and as you say it only works if the element it is applied to is a Control. Therefore, this offers nothing over leaving the TargetType set to Control.

Answer (score -2):

I got this working

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderStyleThin"  TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />

    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
               <Setter Property="Background=" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        </Style.Resources>

</Style>
```