# Why does my style not get picked up?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to apply a style to all `FrameworkElement` objects via a `Style` defined in a `ResourceDictionary`.  In one particular view, I've included the resource dictionary and there's a `TextBox` on it that I want to use that style.

So, here are the two definitions I have played around with:

```
    <!-- STYLE USED BY ALL FRAMEWORK ELEMENTS TO DISPLAY TOOLTIP ON VALIDATION ERROR -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- STYLE USED BY ALL TEXTBOX CONTROLS FOR VALIDATION ERROR DISPLAY -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                               Source="{StaticResource imgDisallow16}" Width="16"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                                BorderThickness="1">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

As written, the style for the `Tooltip` doesn't kick in.  If I give that style a `x:Key` and reference that name directly on the `TextBox`, it works.  But why doesn't the `FrameworkElement` type do it?  Since `TextBox` inherits from it, that is.

Likewise, if I add that `Tooltip` trigger to the second style, that works.  That one does not have a name, but targets `TextBox`.  So why does that work without a name, but the first does not?

EDIT:  here's the `TextBox

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0"
     Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="CurrentEquipment.Name"
         Mode="TwoWay"
         ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True"
         NotifyOnValidationError="True"
         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <vr:EmailValidationRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: It just doesn't work like this. Your `FrameworkElement` style will not be applied to child classes (textboxes, buttons or any else). Styles are matched by type exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBox` style doesn't extend the `FrameworkElement` style unless you explicitly base the former on the latter:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}">
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow.  That seems like the other way around.  I want anything based on `FrameworkElement` to get the Tooltip, no matter what it is.  Not _just TextBoxes_.

Comment: The TextBox elements pick up the implicit TextBox style only but not the TextBox style *and* the FrameworkElement style unless you base the former on the latter as I explained in my answer. So you need to base any implicit control style on your implicit FrameworkElement style.

Comment: The part I'm questioning, then, is that it still seems specific to `TextBox`.  So if I want the same thing for a `ComboBox`, I have to define another style for that, even though they both inherit from `FrameworkElement` and the style definitions will be redundant.

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026635/setting-a-styles-targettype-property-to-a-base-class

Comment: Well, that's unfortunately limited.  So much for inheritance as a useful tool.  Thank you.