# Using Style for ComboBox and TextBox

Tags: wpf

Is there a way I can reuse Styles for more than 1 `TargetType` eg. ComboBox and TextBox

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox, TextBox" />
```

is there such a thing? Or is the only way duplicate the style and target each style to differnt types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you define multiple TargetTypes for one XAML style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802658/can-you-define-multiple-targettypes-for-one-xaml-style)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (if I'm not mistaken).
But what you may do in order to avoid copy-paste is to create a BaseStyle with a key and then create two styles for ComboBox and TextBox which are BasedOn the BaseStyle. smth like that:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
   <Setter ... />
</Style>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle }" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox }" />
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle }" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can provide targettype as control and define setter proeprties of control and apply that style to textbox and combox.