# Can I have one Style with multiple TargetType in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, targettype

As titled, and I mean something like below:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Label}"  
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
```

This is actually for the sake of using a 3rd party control, I have inherited their class.  But the template doesn't apply to the SubClass because the `TargetType` is on the base class.  So I would like to set multiple `TargetType`s to make it able to apply for both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you define multiple TargetTypes for one XAML style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802658/can-you-define-multiple-targettypes-for-one-xaml-style)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No you cannot, however I often create a style for a shared base class such as `FrameworkElement`, and then create my individual control styles that are `BasedOn` the base style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <!-- Shared Setters -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many properties that `FrameworkElement` does not include (such as font-related ones), so they cannot be included in the style setters. You could choose `ContentControl` instead, but that wouldn't work with this particular example, because `TextBlock` does not inherit from `ContentControl.`

Answer (score 11):

A more flexible variation of Rachel's answer is to use resourceKey for BasedOn.

So, instead of:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <!-- Shared Setters -->
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" />
```

Do something like:

```
<Style x:Key="commonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <!-- Shared Setters -->
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource commonStyle}" />
```

This gives more options as some styles can be based on commonStyle, and some on e.g. commonStyle2, where both commonStyle and commonStyle2 have FrameworkElement as target type.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

`TargetType` is a property of Style and can only be set once. To insure type safty, the style should target a specific type in order to know what properties to set.

However, there is a work around. You can take the common properties of all the types you have and define them in one style. Then make specific styles for each of the specific controls and use the [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) property to inherit from the basic style.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Rachel's answer, for cleaner code, you can remove the x:Type within the Markup Extension and just use the Type:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <!-- Shared Setters -->
</Style>
```

Is the same as:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <!-- Shared Setters -->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that in a grid you can only set the style of one item. However, in a stackpanel you can set the style of multiple items.

See this code:

```
<Grid>        
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>Kanban ID</TextBlock>
            <TextBox></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>Customer Name</TextBlock>
            <TextBox></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>            
        <Button>Save</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If you were to remove the  place it below the  and change to  you will see that the objects aren't set, only the last object's properties is changed.

Hope this helps.