# Style defined in a resource section for all controls in a window

Tags: wpf

When we define a Style in an XAML resource section & set it's TargetType property to a specific control type then we do not need to set Style property to control of that type. e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Style set for all buttons"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,56,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" />
        <Button Style="{x:Null}" Content="No Style" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="212,121,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" />
        <Button  Content="Button" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="296,183,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158" />
    </Grid>
```

But when we want to define a style for all controls in a window then we need to add Style property to each control to have that defined style. e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource Style1}" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,52,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Label Style="{StaticResource Style1}" Content="Label" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,99,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" />
    </Grid>
```

Can't we access style "Style1" with Button & Label in above example without setting Style property specifically in Button & Label controls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question as to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802658/can-you-define-multiple-targettypes-for-one-xaml-style)

General consensus is that you cannot apply a style to something as esoteric as just the control.  Considering the wide range of properties and controls, I can understand why the system rejects/ignores it.  I would suggest maybe something like this to get you fairly close to what you would want:

```
<Style x:Key="general" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource general}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"/>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource general}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}"/>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource general}" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it concludes that we can't have common style for all controls by defining only one style targeting 'Control' class. We can use that style for other controls by inheriting this style separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource style1}"/>` for buttons, other for labels and so on...

Comment: Thanks, I understood that a single style targeting 'control' class can't be directly applicable to other controls like Button, Label etc. We need to inherit it from base style.