# Replace Foreground color of all controls

Tags: wpf, xaml

To switch to dark theme I am currently switching merged dictionaries. DarkTheme.xaml contains:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlobalTextColor" Color="#FFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlobalBackColor" Color="#000000" />
```

and then each control template has something like

```
Foreground="{DynamicResource GlobalTextColor}"
```

Is there a more elegant way to replace all text at once like High Contrast theme does (without other style changes of that theme) or promised performance penalty of DynamicResource bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<Style x:Key="Highlight" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

This would set all the foregrounds on each control to red.
This way you can reference it as a static resource.

Source: [Can you define multiple TargetTypes for one XAML style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802658/can-you-define-multiple-targettypes-for-one-xaml-style)

Or another link here: [How to target all controls (WPF Styles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131034/how-to-target-all-controls-wpf-styles)

Comment: Switching the style in MergedDictionaries (user changes theme) did not change the color. Also, I was hoping for some global settings that would replace default text color key

Comment: This is what I know of as best practice. Sorry, I can't really help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the project from the solution explorer(in visual studio) and select open in blend.Then apply the style the needed parts and  you can save it there.You can open another page or and add those styles or you can add it to the same page attributes just selecting the attribute and giving it the saved style.