# WPF: Master/Detail - Disable detail TextBoxes if no records?

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection, master-detail

I have an `ObservableCollection` of custom objects bound via a `DataContext` to a `ListBox`.

Next to the `ListBox` a have a group of `TextBox` that are bound to the current item's field.  (i.e. `Text={Binding Path=/SomeField}`)

How can I disable / grey out the record detail `TextBoxes` when my `DataContext`'s `ObservableCollection` is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- When the collection itself is null -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <!-- When the collection has no items -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: As an added note: You can use style inhertnace if you need to apply this to both `TextBox` and `PasswordBox`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12890047/3975887

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you are using mvvm and have a viewmodel to back up your view - I would create a readonly bool property in your viewmodel and return true if the count of your observable collection > 0.

You can then bind the bool to the isEnabled property of the necessary text boxes, thus enabling or disabling them depending upon the value(s) of your observable collection.

EDIT - As per BenjaminPaul's comment below, the change event must be handled for your observable collection and you should then call propertyChanged on your bool property to ensure is is updated and passed back to the view.

Comment: You will also need to handle the ObservableCollections "CollectionChanged" event too... when this event is raised you will need to raise the PropertyChanged event for your boolean.